# php/datatables generate table using foreach but need an additional <td></td> at end

Tags: php, html

I am using datatables and generating my table using a foreach, but I need one last  to contain the options (edit, etc). I cannot think how to most efficiently do this, I can think to do it using a counter and then when the output has ended place an if statement (rows = rows then) to put these last td's in... I am hoping someone has a better way using my current syntax?

```
                        <?php foreach($results as $row):?>
                            <tr>
                                <?php foreach($row as $cell): ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $cell ?>
                                    </td>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put then after internal for like this:

```
<?php foreach($results as $row):?>
<tr>
<?php foreach($row as $cell): ?>
<td>
<?php echo $cell ?>
</td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<td>edit </td> <td>show</td><td>delete</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Oh man, this is embarrassing..... Trying to do so many things and its starting me in the face! thanks for the help!